# Hyperledger Fabric tutorial "Error: unknown flag: --peerAddresses"

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I am following along the tutorial at http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

I am copy&pasting along the way and opted for the Node.js variants where choice was offered.

```
peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls true --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc --peerAddresses peer0.org1.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.org2.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt -c '{"Args":["invoke","a","b","10"]}'
```

When I get to the code above, it gives me the error "Error: unknown flag: --peerAddresses"

Please see below the terminal history:

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xC5NNQVJyW/

Please do tell if you need additional information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is sort of a half answer but I think you should be following the tutorial for http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/build_network.html (Note: **release-1.1** not **latest**). The only difference is that the endorsement policy when you instantiate is `-P "OR ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"` instead of `-P "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"` and when you invoke the chaincode you only endorse it against one peer (the default being peer0 of org1).

The CLI being able to get endorsements from multiple peers at once is a new feature (ref: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/commit/368b1511e23d55355d572fd267223bb1bd4de890?short_path=6a6833d#diff-6a6833de704771c6c6879904e353c025) and I think the latest docker image for hyperledger/fabric-tools as of this post (1.1.0) does not reflect this change.

Comment: As my question only concerns going through the tutorial and not having two peers endorse a transaction, " half answer" could be an understatement. I will give it a go later today, and select your answer if it works. Thanks