# Chaincode Invoke, Error: unknown flag: --tlsRootCertFiLes

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to invoke my chain code using command taken from hyperledger tutorial:

```
peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile ${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C mychannel -n basic --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt -c '{"function":"InitLedger","Args":[]}'
```

But I get the error that flag is unknown, also error message shows it is known - existed flag. I am so confused.

```
Error: unknown flag: --tlsRootCertFiLes 
Usage:
  peer chaincode invoke [flags]

Flags:
  -C, --channelID string               The channel on which this command should be executed
      --connectionProfile string       Connection profile that provides the necessary connection information for the network. Note: currently only supported for providing peer connection information
  -c, --ctor string                    Constructor message for the chaincode in JSON format (default "{}")
  -h, --help                           help for invoke
  -I, --isInit                         Is this invocation for init (useful for supporting legacy chaincodes in the new lifecycle)
  -n, --name string                    Name of the chaincode
      --peerAddresses stringArray      The addresses of the peers to connect to
      --tlsRootCertFiles stringArray   If TLS is enabled, the paths to the TLS root cert files of the peers to connect to. The order and number of certs specified should match the --peerAddresses flag
      --waitForEvent                   Whether to wait for the event from each peer's deliver filtered service signifying that the 'invoke' transaction has been committed successfully
      --waitForEventTimeout duration   Time to wait for the event from each peer's deliver filtered service signifying that the 'invoke' transaction has been committed successfully (default 30s)

Global Flags:
      --cafile string                       Path to file containing PEM-encoded trusted certificate(s) for the ordering endpoint
      --certfile string                     Path to file containing PEM-encoded X509 public key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
      --clientauth                          Use mutual TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --connTimeout duration                Timeout for client to connect (default 3s)
      --keyfile string                      Path to file containing PEM-encoded private key to use for mutual TLS communication with the orderer endpoint
  -o, --orderer string                      Ordering service endpoint
      --ordererTLSHostnameOverride string   The hostname override to use when validating the TLS connection to the orderer
      --tls                                 Use TLS when communicating with the orderer endpoint
      --tlsHandshakeTimeShift duration      The amount of time to shift backwards for certificate expiration checks during TLS handshakes with the orderer endpoint
      --transient string                    Transient map of arguments in JSON encoding
```

My related path variables:

```
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/home/vagrant/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tl$
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/home/vagrant/fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7051
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error does seem strange.

Is it possible that you are using an older version of Hyperledger Fabric that does not support multiple endorsing nodes?  (I'm referencing [this old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50690506/13856851).)

Have you tested this with an endorsement policy that only requires a single peer node?  (In that case, you could leave out the --tlsRootCertFiLes from your command, since you already provided it as an environmental variable.

Lastly, did you set your FABRIC_CFG_PATH variable?  (e.g. `export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/../config/` )

Comment: I checked version, It was 2.3 the last version. But latest documentation is about currently developing version, so mine is older. I used 2.3 documentation and now I succeed this part. Thank you!